# Create a named range from an inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

I´m trying to create a named range from an inputbox in VBA. This is the code that I have but I can´t get VBA to recognize the name of the range.

```
Dim xRgl As Range
Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Range A:", "Select Range", xTxt, , , , , 8)
Range("xRgl").Font.Italic = True
```

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code `Dim xRgl As Range` instead of `Dim xRg1 As Range` and it should be `xRg1.Font.Italic = True`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to specify the object that the user inputs as a range. Try this:

```
Sub Testing()
    Dim xRgl As Range
    Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Range:", Type:=8)
    xRg1.Font.Italic = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it really helped. I am now trying to autofill my named range with certain values. This is the code that I have but I keep getting Error 13 on my Set fillRange = xRgl line of code. This is the code that I have:

Comment: Range("D5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("D6").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3"
    Range("D7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "4"
    Range("D8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    Range("D9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "6"
    Set SourceRange = Range("D5:D9")
    Set fillRange = xRgl
    SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange